# gcc-4.1 -> gcc-4.8 linker error. New ".text.unlikely" section overlap ".text" section

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, linker-errors, linker-scripts

I'm trying to build cromwell (Original Xbox legal firmware replacement) using a more recent version of gcc but after altering the project compilation setup slightly, ld throws the following error:

> ld: section .text.unlikely loaded at [0000000000000000,0000000000000669] overlaps section .text loaded at [0000000000000000,0000000000021515]

You can clone the project from here if you want to have a look: https://github.com/not404/cromwell

First and foremost, I want to mention I was able to successfully build and run this project(on my Xbox) using gcc-3.3 on a x32 linux VM and gcc-4.1 on cygwin x86 (built gcc for target i686-linux-gnu). I had to remove `-Werror` cflag in the main Makefile to successfully build it in gcc-3.3. Trying to build it using gcc-4.8.2 on a x32 VM after modifying the makefile result in the error mentionned above.

In order to get to there, I modified the CFLAGS in the Makefile in root of the project. I still had `-Werror` removed from CLAGS. I had to add `-fno-stack-protector` flags in `CFLAGS` and `ETH_CFLAGS` to get past the `undefined reference to '__stack_chk_fail'` error. I think this workaround is quite harmless. Older gcc versions didn't support such stack smashing protection mechanism so disabling it should not pose a problem.

After the modifications made to the Makefile, I am presented with the linker error about section overlapping. I read that the `.text.unlikely` section was added around gcc 4.6 so obviously it was not considered when the cromwell project was actively developped!

So, in order to get past this error, I tried to explicitely define the `.text.unlikely` section in the "ldscript-crom.ld" linker script. Originally, script contained the following:

```
.text LOW_ROM : AT ( 0 ){
    _start_low_rom = . ;
    *(.text);
    _end_low_rom = . ;
}
```

I changed it to:

```
    .text LOW_ROM : AT ( 0 ){
    _start_low_rom = . ;
    *(.text);
    *(.text.unlikely);
    _end_low_rom = . ;
}
```

After this change, I get yet another error:

> ld: section .eh_frame loaded at [0000000000000000,00000000000062b3] overlaps section .text loaded at [0000000000000000,0000000000021b7f]

From what I read on the internet, the `.eh_frame` section is only related to exception handling and targeted to C++ to catch exceptions.

I was able to fix this by adding the following flags to CFLAGS and EHT_CFLAGS in the main Makefile:

```
-fno-reorder-functions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables
```

After all that, I finally get an output file. Unfortunately, there are error in execution. It seems to start well but I get no video and execution seem to crash at some point.

I tried to print the map of the linked file but I don't see anything relevant. I won't post the 2 maps(with gcc-3.3 and with gcc-4.8, same ld) here as they are very big. Here is the part of the map containing the `.text.unlikely` section definition(from gcc-4.8):

```
                0x0000000003a216f0                disable
 *fill*         0x0000000003a2170e        0x2 
 .text          0x0000000003a21710      0x165 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/xbox_main.o
                0x0000000003a21710                loadkernel
                0x0000000003a21870                cleanup
 *fill*         0x0000000003a21875        0xb 
 .text          0x0000000003a21880      0x2b5 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/elf.o
                0x0000000003a21880                prepare_boot_params
                0x0000000003a21b20                elf_start
 *fill*         0x0000000003a21b35        0xb 
 .text          0x0000000003a21b40       0x46 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/exec_elf.o
                0x0000000003a21b40                try_elf_boot
 *(.text.unlikely)
                0x0000000003a21b86                _end_low_rom = .

.iplt           0x0000000000000000        0x0
 .iplt          0x0000000000000000        0x0 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/BootStartup.o

.rel.dyn        0x0000000000000000        0x0
 .rel.iplt      0x0000000000000000        0x0 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/BootStartup.o
 .rel.text      0x0000000000000000        0x0 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/BootStartup.o
 .rel.data      0x0000000000000000        0x0 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/BootStartup.o

.rodata         0x0000000003a21b86    0x108b1 load address 0x0000000000021b86
 *(.rodata)
 *fill*         0x0000000003a21b86        0x2
```

Here's the same section from gcc-3.3:

```
                    0x0000000003a1f7a0                disable
     *fill*         0x0000000003a1f7c2        0xe 
     .text          0x0000000003a1f7d0      0x165 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/xbox_main.o
                    0x0000000003a1f7d0                loadkernel
                    0x0000000003a1f930                cleanup
     *fill*         0x0000000003a1f935        0xb 
     .text          0x0000000003a1f940      0x2b6 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/elf.o
                    0x0000000003a1f940                prepare_boot_params
                    0x0000000003a1fbe0                elf_start
     *fill*         0x0000000003a1fbf6        0xa 
     .text          0x0000000003a1fc00       0x33 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/exec_elf.o
                    0x0000000003a1fc00                try_elf_boot
                    0x0000000003a1fc33                _end_low_rom = .

    .iplt           0x0000000000000000        0x0
     .iplt          0x0000000000000000        0x0 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/BootStartup.o

    .rel.dyn        0x0000000000000000        0x0
     .rel.iplt      0x0000000000000000        0x0 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/BootStartup.o
     .rel.text      0x0000000000000000        0x0 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/BootStartup.o
     .rel.data      0x0000000000000000        0x0 /home/cromwelldev/workspace/cromwell/obj/BootStartup.o

    .rodata         0x0000000003a1fc33    0x11024 load address 0x000000000001fc33
     *(.rodata)
```

I think the problem reside in the `.text.unlikely` section I put in the linker script. I must say I'm at lost here. I'm not familiar with linker scripts so much so I really don't know what to do.

Is there a way to build the project without separating the `.text.unlikely` section from the rest of the `.text` section? Would that be a way to solve my problem?

I also think `-fno-reorder-functions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` flags are not a solution to my problem. In such project, there are elements that need to be at specific memory locations and I fear these flags do move things around in a bad way!

Thank you in advance!

Ben

Answer (score 1):

According to [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) the linker might choose to put stuff into the sections `.text.hot` and `.text.unlikely` if option `-freorder-functions` is activated (which is default at optimization levels -O2, -O3, -Os).
Depending on whether it "thinks" that a function is called very often or not. I guess this might give you some optimization potential if your hardware has something like fast and slow memory areas.
 
If not - just adding these sections to the .text should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you did to fix the error about `.text.unlikely` overlapping `.text` is actually correct -- the linker error is caused by the linker "punting" to beginning the `.text.unlikely` section at load address 0 because the linker script does not specify anywhere for it to go.  Repeating the linker script change for the `.eh_frame` section and removing the `-fno-reorder-functions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` compiler flags should correct the error about `.eh_frame` overlapping `.text` without causing further trouble downstream.